# Оптимизация запроса в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Приветствую, появилась проблема в ходе увеличения количества записей в бд.
Вот такой запрос выполняется ~6s

```
SELECT u.steamid, u.name AS u_name, u.img AS u_img, w.name As w_name, w.category, comb.case_id, w.id AS w_id, u.fake AS _f
  FROM tb_opened o
    INNER JOIN tb_users u ON o.steamid = u.steamid
      INNER JOIN tb_combiner comb ON comb.id = o.weap
        INNER JOIN tb_weapons w ON w.id = comb.weap_id
          ORDER BY o.id DESC LIMIT 25;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимизировать.

Вот структура таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

EXPLAIN моего запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу справиться с правильным ограничением по количеству выборки

Comment: _EXPLAIN моего запроса_ Ну из него сразу видно, что у двух таблиц нет подходящего для оптимизации запроса индекса. ВЫ бы структуру таблиц показали не как фотографию, а как DDL, что ли...

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос просматривает таблицы **o** и **u** полностью. В случае с
таблицей **o** это нормально. Там нужно взять и просмотреть каждую
строку исходя из смысла задачи.  **u** - другое дело. Тут нужно найти
строки только с определёнными значениями **steamid**. Но MySQL сейчас
ищет эти значения просматривая все строки подряд. Создайте индекс на
столбце **u.steamid**. Это ускорит поиск, поскольку для каждого
значения **steamid** будет вместо N строк (сколько всего есть в
таблице **u**) просмотрено log(N). Это, конечно, примерный подсчёт,
ведь он верен только для бинарного дерева поиска, а индексы бывают не
только на нём основаны. Но в любом случае будет намного быстрее.

С таблицами **comb** и **w** всё в порядке. Там объединение идёт по 
первичному ключу. А он по определению индекс.

Ну а LIMIT Вам не поможет. Он работает поверх готового набора данных. Вы ведь из объединения нескольких таблиц информацию запрашиваете, а не из одной. Сначала
производится объединение, на которое уходит основное время, потом   сортировка         по убыванию с помощью DESC. Это тоже дело не быстрое, ведь сортировать СУБД будет все найденные строки, а их могут быть тысячи. И только потом из этого отсортированного набора данных размером в несколько тысяч строк будут взяты первые 25 с помощью LIMIT. Короче говоря, в Вашем случае если LIMIT и даёт какое-то ускорение, то только засчёт меньшего времени на отдачу результата пользователю. На время поиска по таблицам он не влияет вообще, если вызывается после объединений и сортировок.